# How to load images after i scroll to that section of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load the images an give them a wow-effect after I'd scrolled down to that section of the page. Try [this site](http://www.cilantrotech.com/). And scroll down, you'll see that the images are loaded after the page has been scrolled to that section. I'm sure that's not **lazy-loading** in jQuery. How can I do it ?

I tried searching on Google, but couldn't get the exact/related name to be tried/searched for.

How can I achieve the same?

Thanks

Comment: All the images load at once for me...

Comment: No. Scroll Down to the section where its written `Our Structured Approach to Resource Management`

Comment: Bind window scroll and animate images in right position with bounceOut transition effect.

Comment: Is there any specific tutorial that you can point me to OR can you provide a sample code/jsFiddle link? Thanks

Comment: @user1162512 Typically you are meant to post what you've tried and we can help you with it. You can't expect people do make a sample for you from scratch.

Comment: @MathewMacLean - I understand the norms of SO, but I didnt had any prior knowledge on the same topic, neither I knew the  exact 'name' of the this type of functionality. Had I been knowing, I would've googled and tried initially. But without any knowledge, how would I try? :)

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: @user1162512 the images show up when I scroll, but they're preloaded.

Comment: @maxton- Yes. I want exactly the same thing. Any idea how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's called Lazy Loading.

Here's a tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/

Here's a jQuery plugin:

http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Comment: This i snot lazy loading. It's kind of an animation.

Comment: Lazy loading means loading images when the user scrolls to them. You can load with whatever animation you want.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports an onscroll event. Check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). You may right code to load these images on scroll.
The page also has a working demo of the event